# Why is my function getting rejected by my autograder?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, operators

For the following problem:

> We have a loud talking parrot. The `hour` parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return `True` if we are in trouble.

I wrote the following function:

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if talking == True and hour >= 20 or hour <= 7:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

It is not working as expected when the arguments are:

```
parrot_trouble(True, 20)
parrot_trouble(False, 6)
parrot_trouble(True, 7)
```

I must be using the operators incorrectly, but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems here is [*operator precedence*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). When you put a boolean statement that says `A and B or C` it's unclear whether you mean `(A and B) or C` or `A and (B or C)`. In Python (and in fact most languages), `and` has a higher precedence than `or`, so the condition is treated as if it is `(A and B) or C`. In this case, that is not what you are looking for. The correct statement would be:

```py
  if talking == True and (hour >= 20 or hour <= 7):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function as below:

```
def parrot_trouble(Talking, hour):
    return Talking == True and (hour > 20 or hour <7)

print(parrot_trouble(False, 21))
```